# Java, LinkedList of Strings. Insert in alphabetical order

Tags: java, insert, linked-list

I have a simple linked list. The node contains a string (value) and an int (count).

In the linkedlist when I insert I need to insert the new Node in alphabetical order. If there is a node with the same value in the list, then I simply increment the count of the node.

I think I got my method really screwed up.

```
 public void addToList(Node node){
        //check if list is empty, if so insert at head
        if(count == 0 ){
            head = node;
            head.setNext(null);
            count++;
        }
        else{
            Node temp = head;
            for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
                //if value is greater, insert after
                if(node.getItem().getValue().compareTo(temp.getItem().getValue()) > 0){
                    node.setNext(temp.getNext());
                    temp.setNext(node);                   
                }
                //if value is equal just increment the counter
                else if(node.getItem().getValue().compareTo(temp.getItem().getValue()) == 0){
                    temp.getItem().setCount(temp.getItem().getCount() + 1);
                }
                //else insert before
                else{
                    node.setNext(temp);
                }
            }
        }      

    }
```

Ok so this is inserting all my strings, but not in alphabetical order. Do you see any error?

```
 public Node findIsertionPoint(Node head, Node node){
        if( head == null)
            return null;

        Node curr = head;
        while( curr != null){
            if( curr.getValue().compareTo(node.getValue()) == 0)
                return curr;
            else if( curr.getNext() == null || curr.getNext().getValue().compareTo(node.getValue()) > 0)
                return curr;
            else
                curr = curr.getNext();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void insert(Node node){
        Node newNode = node;
        Node insertPoint = this.findIsertionPoint(this.head, node);
        if( insertPoint == null)
            this.head = newNode;
        else{
            if( insertPoint.getValue().compareTo(node.getValue()) == 0)
                insertPoint.getItem().incrementCount();
            else{
                newNode.setNext(insertPoint.getNext());
                insertPoint.setNext(newNode);
            }
        }
        count++;
    }
```

Comment: @user69: I see that you've adapted my pseudocode to Java. Nice job so far, but for some reason you're still leaving out the logic to insert before `head` when `head` is not `null` and the inserted value is less than `head`'s value. Please look at my pseudocode again. If you don't understand it, ask. There's a reason why everything's there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few bugs with your code:

- Inserting at/before `head` actually needs to happen in two different scenarios:

  - If the list is empty, `head` becomes `node`
  - If the list is not empty, but `node` is less than the first element, `head` also becomes `node`

    - In either case, `node` links to whatever `head` was pointing to before (`null` or a real node), and `head` now points to `node`.
- If you're not inserting *before* `head`, then you must be inserting *after* some node. We just need to find where this place is. There are two scenarios:

  - `node.getValue() > temp.getValue()`, and `node.getValue() < temp.getNext().getValue()`
  - `node.getValue() > temp.getValue()` and `temp.getNext() == null`

    - In either case, `node` is inserted between `temp` and `temp.getNext()`

I suggest encapsulating the *after* insertion point search in its own function. That is, given the list and a value, it needs to return a node. If that node has the same value as the search value, then simply increment; otherwise, insert *after*. As a special case, return `null` to indicate that the insertion point is *before* `head`.

---

In pseudocode, it'll look like this:

```
FUNCTION findInsertionPoint(Node head, V value) RETURNS Node
  // return null if value needs to be inserted before head
  IF head == null OR value < head.getValue()
     RETURN null;

  // otherwise, either return a node with the given value,
  // or return a node after which value should be inserted
  Node curr = head;
  REPEAT
     IF curr.value == value
        RETURN curr;
     ELSEIF curr.getNext() == null OR curr.getNext().getValue() > value
        RETURN curr;
     ELSE
        curr = curr.getNext();

PROCEDURE insert(V value) {
  Node newNode = NEW Node(value);
  Node insertPoint = findInsertionPoint(this.head, value);
  IF insertPoint == null // insert before head
     newNode.setNext(this.head);
     this.head = newNode;
  ELSE
     IF insertPoint.getValue() == value
        insertPoint.incrementCounter();
     ELSE // insert after insertPoint
        newNode.setNext(insertPoint.getNext());
        insertPoint.setNext(newNode);
```

---

*Update*: I see that you've translated my pseudocode to Java, but for some reason you've omitted codes that deals with inserting before `head` when `head` is not empty. Specifically, you have inexplicably omitted this part:

```
IF head == null OR value < head.getValue()
             // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and this part:

```
IF insertPoint == null 
   newNode.setNext(this.head); // <<<<<<<<<<<
   this.head = newNode;
```

Both of these are *essential*; it's what allows `"A"` to be inserted before the `head` in `[ "B", "C", "D" ]`.

You need to understand why they're important, and *really* ask yourself why you chose to remove them. Explain to us, to me, to yourself, why you did that; realize the mistake and learn from it.

Comment: Hey you were right.... actually I missed one line of code.... not sure why I did that, wasn't paying attention.

Comment: @user69: get the most out of the pseudocode, namely learn: (i) how to address all of the "different" scenarios, and see if they can be simplified to just a few (ii) how to encapsulate helper logic, testable and reusable on its own.

Answer (score 1):

For making this, instead of developing from scratch my own sorted list I would implement the Queue interface or extend the already existing PriorityQueue (or any other sorted collection that may apply better). I would define the Node class as an implementation of the Comparable interface  or instantiate my queue with a Comparator instance and override the PriorityQueue add method to add the new Node only if another object is not already in the queue, incrementing the counter otherwise. If using java >5.0 for type safety I would use generic to allow just Node objects in the Queue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use one of [Multiset](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) implementations from Google Collections.

A Multiset works similar to a Set, but allows for duplicates (and counts them!). Look at [TreeMultiset](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html):

> A multiset which maintains the
>   ordering of its elements, according to
>   either their natural order or an
>   explicit Comparator.

Comment: No I want to create my own linked list

Comment: @user69514: not the best idea there.. But anyway if you want to maintain it by yourself then use the standard `Map` where each `key` is one of your strings and `value` is a counter. `LinkedList` is probably the worst choice for maintaining the data structure which you've described.

Comment: this is homework, he has to write his own list implementation, as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the complete code it's hard to do debugging.
I think the problem is that you set

```
 Node temp = head;
```

before the loop, but you need to reassign `temp` while while traversing the list to the current element. In this case you continue to compare against `head`.

Answer (score 0):

- You've taken care of the case when
  the `list` is initially empty. You
  should also take care of the special
  case when the new node goes at be
  beginning of the list. If your list
  is `B->C->D` and you are inserting `A`.
- Its good to set `node.next` to `null`(If not already done). So
  that if the node gets inserted at the
  end, we have `null` as the next of the
  last node.
- You need to update the temp to move
  to the next node if no insertion is
  possible. So you are missing a `temp = temp.next;`

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework I'm not going to give you any source code.  There is one big issue I see with the code:

Suppose your list already has two distinct items, and you're inserting a new item.  In your code, you are checking whether `node` is greater than `head`, and if so inserting it immediately after, ignoring the rest of the items in the list.

You code do something like this.  There are some missing details which you can fill in yourself.

1. If list is empty, set `head = node`, `head->next = NULL`, and you're done.
2. Otherwise if `node->value < head->value`,  set `node->next = head, head = node`.
3. Otherwise, if `node->value == head->value`, `head->count++`;
4. Otherwise, set `tmp = head`.  While `tmp->next->value < node->value`,   set `tmp=tmp->next`. (check for nulls!).
5. If `tmp->next == NULL`, (i.e. you reached end of list) then set `tmp->next = node`, and you're done.
6. Otherwise if `tmp->next->value == node->value`, (i.e. you reached a node with same value) `tmp->next->count++`.
7. Otherwise, if `node->next = tmp->next, tmp->next = node`, and exit